# Running time of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, performance, recursion

The following algorithm(uses dynamic programming) takes the input: `C` is an integer, `p` is an array containing integers, and `n` is the size of `p`. Note that the code is pseudo code.

```
Start(C, p, n)
   let mem[1..C, 1..n] be a multi-dimensional array
   for i=1 to C
      for j=1 to n
         mem[i,j] = -1
   return Count(C, p, n, mem)

Count(C, p, i, mem)
   if mem[C, i] >= 0
      return mem[C, i]
   if C==0
      q = 1
   elif n < 1 or C < 0
      q = 0
   else
      q = Count(C - p[i], p, i-1, mem) + Count(C, p, i-1, mem)
   mem[C, i] = q
   return q
```

Why is the running time of this implementation said to be O(n*C)?

For each subproblem in `Count`, there is at max `i-1` subproblems and we solve two of these, `Count(C - p[i], p, i-1, mem)` and `Count(C, p, i-1, mem)`.

Thus, why is the running time not O(n^2)? I mean if we for each subproblem solves i-1 subproblems*2, we get an arithmetic series which is O(n^2)? If I am wrong, please tell me :)

Our `C` is positive but otherwise there it is not bounded. `C` might be bigger than `n` in which case I see that `n*C > n*n` which implies `O(n*C)` because of the initialization of the array in `Start`. However,  if `C` is smaller than n, then `n*C < n*n` which implies `O(n^2)`. So would you say `O(n*C)` or `O(n^2)` - why, why not?

Comment: I think you've figured it out on your own. You don't know if C>n or C<n, so you can't factor out C.

Comment: @MarkRansom So with that argument, would you say O(n*C)?

Comment: Assuming your analysis is correct, which I haven't spent any time checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime of this code is O(nC). One way to see this is that there are O(nC) total elements in the table and you're spending O(1) time filling in each one of them, thanks to how the memoization works.

Your question seems to boil down to whether you can rewrite O(nC) as O(n<sup>2</sup>). That depends on what C is. If C is something that can vary independently of n (for example, if C can be 10<sup>20</sup> while n = 3) then O(nC) can't be simplified to O(n<sup>2</sup>).

On the other hand, if C is somehow constrained in a way that depends on n (say, you know that C ≤ n), then you could say that the runtime is O(n<sup>2</sup>). The question then would be whether this is a useful bound. O(nC) is more precise than O(n<sup>2</sup>) because it more directly indicates that the runtime cost depends on both n and C, and for small C you'll get a better indication of how long things will take with O(nC) than you would if you used O(n<sup>2</sup>) as a bound.

Hope this helps!